# Is there Any Way to Make Android Stay on the Same Page on the Application Drawer after Pressing the Home Button?

Tags: stock-android, app-drawer

Often, I press the home button to end an unresponsive app, with intentions of starting the app back up. However, when I open back up the application drawer, it is always on the first page, and not the page I was previously on, which wastes time. Is there any setting that can change this so that the last page visited will be reopened? (LG Nexus 5, Running Android 4.4.4) I apologise for the terrible question, I know it's probably just the way things are, but it can get irritating. Perhaps, if it is not possible to change this, I will have to get into the habit of searching for apps using "Google Now" on my home screen, but, in the meantime, I shall wait and see. Thank you for any contribution.

EDIT: I am new to this, so I may have tagged something irrelevant or placed my question in the wrong place etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The app drawer is a part of the launcher app, so you can replace it simply by switching to a different launcher. Just install a new launcher of your choice that works the way you like.

Comment: Thank you for your feedback, although I do like the google now launcher; I shall try find one that works to my needs.

Comment: @BenPorter if the answer solved your issue (as far as that's possible), please don't forget to mark it such using the check-box next to it. This helps other people with similar issues to identify "questions having solutions". Thanks! // And to get your replacement-search booted, you might wish to take a look at [this list of launchers](http://android.izzysoft.de/applists.php?topic=cat;id=179) ;)

Comment: @Izzy Thank you very much once more, your willingness to help is very good to see! I shall do so on any answers that solve my questions in the future!